# Calling VirusTotal API 2.0 always returns "The requested resource is not among the finished, queued or pending scans" no matter what I do

Tags: php, antivirus

I am using a file upload feature on my PHP/Javascript/jQuery website, and using SwiftMailer to send the file as attachment to an e-mail.

However, it's been days I'm desperately trying to get the file to go through VirusTotal API scanning before I can have it sent.

Here are the documentation pages I used:

- https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002146469-API-Scripts
- https://developers.virustotal.com/reference#getting-started
- https://github.com/IzzySoft/virustotal

among many others. Of course, I already have my API key for the public API.

I already tried to send the file using AdrianTNT and IzzyOnDroid's scripts, but no matter what I try, I always get the same reply from VirusTotal in **verbose_msg**:

> The requested resource is not among the finished, queued or pending scans

The **scan_id** remains null.

The funny thing is, VirusTotal should take my file and put it in queue for scanning, so next time I try to upload the same file, the API should reply "-2" (queued) or "1" (got results). But it just doesn't, it keeps answering 0 and the message above...

Here's my current code with IzzyOnDroid's script:

```
//Enclose attachment if it exists
if(isset($_FILES['enclosedFile'])) {
    //Security control on file cleared
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['enclosedFile']['tmp_name']) && 
virusTotalApproval2($_FILES['enclosedFile']['tmp_name'])==1)
    {
        //Enclose attachment to prepared message
        $message->attach(
            Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['enclosedFile']['tmp_name'])->setFilename($_FILES['enclosedFile']['name'])
    );
    //Send message (along with attachment)
    sendMessage($result,$mailer,$message);
}
//Security control on file failed
else{
    echo 'security_issue';
}
}
else{
//Send message without attachment
sendMessage($result,$mailer,$message);
}

require_once("virustotal/virustotal.class.php");

function virusTotalApproval2($fileToScan) {
$apikey = "my_api_key";
$vt = new virustotal($apikey);
$hash = hash('sha256', file_get_contents($fileToScan));
$res = $vt->checkFile($fileToScan); // $hash is optional. Pass the $scan_id if you have it, or the file hash
switch($res) {
  case -99: // API limit exceeded
    // deal with it here – best by waiting a little before trying again :)
    error_log('\nReturned -99');
    return -99;
  case  -1: // an error occured
    // deal with it here
    error_log('\nReturned -1');
    return -1;
  case   0: // no results (yet) – but the file is already enqueued at VirusTotal
    $scan_id = $vt->getScanId();
    $json_response = $vt->getResponse();
    error_log('\nReturned 0');
    return 0;
  case   1: // results are available
    $json_response = $vt->getResponse();
    error_log('\nReturned 1');
    return 1;
  default : // you should not reach this point if you've placed the break before :)
}
// deal with the JSON response here
}
```

At a certain point, I thought it was because of the tmp file, so I tried providing a file I store on the server (though this is not recommended since I suspect the file to be infected) using **move_uploaded_file** instead of **is_uploaded_file** with each of the two scripts:

```
//Initialize tmp dir and filepath
$tmpdir = 'C:/WAMP/www/server/files/';
$fileName = basename($_FILES['enclosedFile']['name']);

//Enclose attachment if it exists
if(isset($_FILES['enclosedFile'])) {
    //Security control on file cleared
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['enclosedFile']['tmp_name'],$tmpdir.$fileName) && virusTotalApproval2($tmpdir.$fileName)==1)
    {
        //Enclose attachment to prepared message
        $message->attach(
        Swift_Attachment::fromPath($tmpdir.$fileName)->setFilename($_FILES['enclosedFile']['name'])
    );
        //Send message (along with attachment)
        sendMessage($result,$mailer,$message);
    }
    //Security control on file failed
    else{
        echo 'security_issue';
    }
}else{
    //Send message without attachment
    sendMessage($result,$mailer,$message);
}
```

But the result remains the same.
With AdrianTNT's script, here's my code:

```
//Returns false if there is a problem with the file, or else true
function virusTotalApproval($fileToScan){
// edit the virustotal.com api key, get one from the site
$virustotal_api_key = "my_api_key";

// get the file size in mb, we will use it to know at what url to send for scanning (it's a different URL for over 30MB)
$file_size_mb = filesize($fileToScan)/1024/1024;
error_log('File size: '.$file_size_mb);

// calculate a hash of this file, we will use it as an unique ID when querying about this file
$file_hash = hash('sha256', file_get_contents($fileToScan));


// [PART 1] hecking if a report for this file already exists (check by providing the file hash (md5/sha1/sha256) 
// or by providing a scan_id that you receive when posting a new file for scanning
// !!! NOTE that scan_id is the only one that indicates file is queued/pending, the others will only report once scan is completed !!!
$report_url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report?apikey='.$virustotal_api_key."&resource=".$file_hash;

$api_reply = file_get_contents($report_url);
error_log('api reply: '.$api_reply);

// convert the json reply to an array of variables
$api_reply_array = json_decode($api_reply, true);

// your resource is queued for analysis
if($api_reply_array['response_code']==-2){
    error_log('\nThe answer is -2, file queued.');
}

// reply is OK (it contains an antivirus report)
// use the variables from $api_reply_array to process the antivirus data
if($api_reply_array['response_code']==1){
    error_log("\nThe answer is 1, file known. We got an antivirus report, there were ".$api_reply_array['positives']." positives found. Here is the full data: \n\n");
    if($api_reply_array['positives']>0)
    {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

// [PART 2] a report for this file was not found, upload file for scanning
if($api_reply_array['response_code']=='0'){
    error_log('The answer is 0, I  don\'t know about that file, but I\'ll take it for scanning and keep you posted.');

    // default url where to post files
    $post_url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan';

    // get a special URL for uploading files larger than 32MB (up to 200MB)
    if($file_size_mb >= 32){
        $api_reply = @file_get_contents('https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan/upload_url?apikey='.$virustotal_api_key);
        $api_reply_array = json_decode($api_reply, true);
        if(isset($api_reply_array['upload_url']) and $api_reply_array['upload_url']!=''){
            $post_url = $api_reply_array['upload_url'];
        }
    }

    // send a file for checking

    // curl will accept an array here too:
    $post['apikey'] = $virustotal_api_key;
    $post['file'] = '@'.$fileToScan;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$post_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $api_reply = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    $api_reply_array = json_decode($api_reply, true);

    if($api_reply_array['response_code']==1){
        error_log('Uuuh, it\'s 1 again now...');
        error_log("\nfile queued OK, you can use this scan_id to check the scan progress:\n".$api_reply_array['scan_id']);
        error_log("\nor just keep checking using the file hash, but it will only report once it is completed (no 'PENDING/QUEUED' reply will be given).");
    }
    else{
        error_log('File hasnt been queued successfully, but verbose msg says: '.$api_reply_array['verbose_msg'].' and scan id says: '.$api_reply_array['scan_id']);
    }

}
}
```

No matter which of the two I choose to use, the result remains the same.

When I consult my API key's panel, I see the amount of times I interrogated the API in "All", and always 0 Failed, 0 Success... it means that the API is getting my files, but is somehow refusing to process them, for a reason that it doesn't explain well enough to me...

I know my code has plenty of optimization to do and I haven't managed yet the situation in which the file is infected with IzzyOnDroid's script, but I'll do this later.

Other intel:
- I tried deactivating my antivirus, following a topic I saw on the net, it didn't change anything.
- I tried uploading a file through the website, and then the API answered 1 about that file since now it knows it, so that part is fine.
- The file I'm trying to upload now is unknown to VirusTotal and is not infected. It's a PDF file.

Thank you for your help.